# How to create angular transclusion component with ng-content removed from DOM on demand?

Tags: angular

I use a lot of vendor modal components in my application. Since settings of all modals are the same but the content is different I would like to create the next component with embedded content:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
    <!-- vendor directive -->
    <div *ngIf="shown" mdbModal #form="mdb-modal" [config]="{ show: true }" class="modal fade scrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" (onHidden)="onHidden()">
      <!-- some common code here -->
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <!-- some common code here -->
    </div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() shown = false;
  @Output() shownChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  @ViewChild('form') form;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onHidden() {
    this.shown = false;
  }
}
```

Then I would like to use it in parent component like this:

```
<app-modal [(shown)]="isModalShown">
  <!-- embedded html with parent scope -->
  <p>{{test.field}}</p>
  ...
</app-modal>
```

And parent component ts:

```
isModalShown = false; // set to true only when "test" data is prepared
test = null; // data to be prepared
```

I've added "test" for simplicity - it shows the problem (I have data that is valid only when "isModalShown" is true). So I want ng-content to be removed from DOM in other cases and expect such behavior. But in reality I get parsing error of accessing undefined "test.field" property:

```
ERROR
Error: Cannot read property 'field' of null
Error: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

What should I do to create component with correct behavior, that is, not be present in DOM at all if boolean flag is false (so checking test with ? operator is not an option)?

The problem can be solved in such a way:

```
<app-modal [(shown)]="isModalShown">
  <ng-container *ngIf="isModalShown">
    <p>{{test.field}}</p>
  </ng-container>
</app-modal>
```

But it's senseless to create such components that I need to double check manually every time. Any better solution?

Comment: `*ngIf="test"`?

Comment: @JBNizet I updated post for you. This is not a good solution and it doesn't answer the question why does angular behave so in this situation.

Comment: You don't want a component to be in the DOM. That's what ngIf allows. Why isn't it a good solution? As to the reason why it behaves like this: because there is no ngIf preventing that part of the template to be evaluated.

Comment: @JBNizet But ngIf is present in modal component so I expect ng-content not be present in DOM and thus test.field which is inside that ng-content

Comment: @JBNizet using such if in every modal leads to the next logical desire - to move <app-modal> with if checking to new component, and the problem is repeated again there.

Comment: Let's take this JS code: `function displayModal(content) { if (shown) console.log(content); } displayModal(test.field)`. Will `test.field`be evaluated, even though `shown` is false? Yes, it will. Same here.

Comment: @JBNizet I got your idea, thank you.